# I can't understand this dialogue from my textbook. Can you help?

Tags: meaning

This character has a $300 allowance. She was asked what would she do if she ran out of allowance money.

Her response: 我父母给了我一张银行卡，在紧急情况下，我可以去拿钱。但是如果没有紧急情况，我用钱用得多了，他们下个月就不给我那么多钱了。比如，

I'm confused because of this sentence: 但是如果没有紧急情况，我用钱用得多了，他们下个月就不给我那么多钱了。

So if the character spent a little bit of money on something that was not urgent, the character's parents will still give the character the same amount of money next month? Because it says only when this character spends a lot of money, her parents won't give her money next month?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure how you got your English translation! The sentence "但是如果没有紧急情况，我用钱用得多了，他们下个月就不给我那么多钱了", translated, would be "but if it isn't an emergency, and I use too much money, my parents next month just won't give me that much money".

The two discrepancies between your translation and the English are in "我用钱用得多了" and "就不给我那么多钱了".

"我用钱用得多了" uses the 得 character, to provide description for a verb. You may be familiar with "跑步跑得快“, for example, which would be a way to say "runs fast". In the same way, the descriptive word in this phrase is "多", which describes the verb "用钱", or "spend money". And, of course, "多" means "much", rather than "little". "Spend only a little" could be better translated as "我用钱用得少了”.

The second area of discrepancy is in "就不给我那么多钱了", which translates literally to "just won't give me that much money", where 就 = just, 不给 = won't give, 我 = me, 那么多 = that much, 钱 = money. I would assume this simply means the parents would take the surplus spending out of next month's allowance.

Your translation, translated back into Chinese, would give something more along the lines of "但是如果没有紧急情况，我用钱用得少了，他们下个月就给我一样多钱了".

Answer (score 0):

我父母给了我一张银行卡，在紧急情况下，我可以去拿钱。
My parents gave me a bank card, in an emergency, I can withdraw money.

但是如果没有紧急情况，我用钱用得多了，他们下个月就不给我那么多钱了。
But if it is not an emergency, (and) I spend too much, next month they will give me less money.

"But Mum, it absolutely was an emergency!! I absolutely needed that new red bag, I swear by all that's holy!"
“可是妈妈，这绝对是紧急情况！！ 我真的需要那个新的红袋子，我发誓我绝没有撒谎！”